# Graph API event webLink appears to be broken

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

The webLink returned with an Office 365 / [Graph API event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/event), is only partially functional. With the right permissions, it allows me to pull up an editable event as follows:

[image]

,,, but, the "Accept / Send the response now" menu item sends the wrong POST:

```
https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application/bond-compact-binary&client-id=NO_AUTH ...
```

... and, the event is never "accepted".

Instead, a POST should be sent as follows:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc?action=RespondToCalendarEvent&EP=1&ID=-49&AC=1
```

... which, will "accept" the event.

Given the `client-id=NO_AUTH`item in the first POST, I am thinking this is an authentication issue, even though the webLink requires an Office 365 login to access. It appears that the browser's session, is not being passed through to the JavaScript.

Any help here?

Comment: This bug has been fixed by Microsoft.